# .Net Core custom log-message format

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging

Is it possible to override or customize the built in logger in .net core to have a special formatted message?

For example, when doing some logging:

```
class A
{
    private readonly ILogger<A> _logger;
    public A(ILogger<A> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public DoStuff()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Start of function");
    }
}
```

The problem is, I would like to have the message end up like this:

```
7/4/2022 Start of function 123456789
```

In other words maybe some prefixes, suffixes, all in uppercase or something else. And I want ALL the logging messages to be in the same way without me building them all the time (and of course I don't want to do it using a function either like `_logger.LogInformation(func("Start of function"))`).

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Logging, only? No Frameworks on top like NLog, Serilog or the like?

Comment: For the MS-Loggers you have limited built-in options or you can use a [custom formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter#implement-a-custom-formatter)

Comment: Hi, no we're not using any framework. I could however maybe use serilog if that will make it easier.

Comment: Serilog gives you the possibility to configure a template a little more conveniently. But it's up to you if that will justify the added overhead of serilog for your project. I'd simply roll a little "Proof-Of-Concept" Project to test it out before adopting any solution into your main project.

Comment: I really like the serilog approach actually .. maybe we will look into a switch to that one. It seems to have endless ways of doing things. :-) thank you Fildor

Comment: You actually can back the Microsoft Logging API with Serilog. So you do not have to refactor gazillion lines of code. Most of the commonly used Logging Frameworks support this. You basically add the libs and configure the app to using serilog in the background and you can continue using the same API you are already used to.

Comment: Yes EXACTLY and that is really nice :-) Thank you Fildor for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use logger factory

```
ILoggerFactory loggerFactory =
            LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
                builder.AddSimpleConsole(options =>
                {
                    options.IncludeScopes = true;
                    options.SingleLine = true;
                    options.TimestampFormat = "hh:mm:ss ";
                    options.CustomPrefix = " ~~~~~ ");
                }));
```

[There](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/console-log-formatter) you can see more

Comment: Hi, I think this is the answer if you need to keep the ms logger. Not sure though if I can leave all old code as-is, it looks like you need to start using the loggerFactory for DI instead. I will however look into the serilog way instead. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works for the Console provider